# Images in kiwi logo slider(wordpress plugin) are tiny in safari

Tags: css, plugins, safari, wordpress

[The problem page](http://www.elsyf-staging.com/esm/)

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej0FL.png)

[image: How it is]

So this is an interesting issue. On every browser except safari, The images display normally. However, in safari, they are super tiny.

```
.bx-wrapper ul.kiwi-logo-carousel.align-center li img {
    max-height: 60%;
    max-width: 76%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The only things that my research on this issue has turned up were ineffective in solving the issue:

[First attempt](https://bootstrapstudio.io/forums/topic/responsive-images-are-small-in-safari/)

[Second Attempt](http://forum.bytesforall.com/showthread.php?t=20510)

Comment: You must reformulate this question. Tips provide screen shoot of the two stages safari and other browsers. You should also mention you are using a plugin and Wordpress. And finally provide a link to the page with the issue not a link to the whole site. Thanks

Comment: There is only one page, the problem page. It is the page that is linked. But I'll update with the screenshots and mention wordpress/plugin for wordpress. I just figured that since this problem can be solved with just CSS, Why add more elements to confuse the audience. I guess I thought wrong,

Comment: Updated the question. Hope there is enough information now, Let me know if there isn't.

Comment: It is worth noting that the Height and Width attributes distort the logos, and thus makes that solution not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by targeting Safari only in CSS.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome, .bx-wrapper ul.kiwi-logo-carousel.align-center li img {
        max-height: none;
        max-width: none;
   }
}
```